have + something + mixed

suspension
4 [count] technical : a substance (usually a liquid) that has very small pieces of a solid material mixed throughout it

https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/suspension

Could "mixed throughout it" be seen as a reduced relative clause?
Would the definition still be natural if "that have been" were inserted before "mixed"?



a substance (usually a liquid) that has very small pieces of a solid material (that have been) mixed throughout it

Yes, mixed throughout it is a reduced relative clause; the deleted words are in parentheses.  Wikipedia explains whiz deletion:

... whiz deletion is a form of ellipsis common in the English language in which a relative pronoun and a form of the verb “to be” are both deleted.

Both versions are fine, but I prefer the shorter one.
